# ReactJs calculate sum of all values present in Table column

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I am having a Bootstrap-table rendering values from service called in componentDidMount().

Example of my table -

```
  Col1      Col2 Col3
   1         2    3
   4         5    6
   7         8    9
  SumValue  15   18 //This last row holds sum of all values
```

How to calculate SumValue of all the values present in col1 and display in Footer.

Below is the code how i am using react-row for mapping data to rows. 
And **value** is the variable holding data of all columns present in json file returned from service, after setting it to the component's state.

```
    {this.state.value && this.state.value.map(function (value, ind) {
                    return <Row key={ind} item={value}></Row>
                })
            }
```

Initializing state

```
   constructor(props){
    super(props)
    {
        this.state ={
            value: [],   //Initializing an array
            SumValue: '',
            default: false,               
        }            
    }
```

Setting state

```
  fetch('https://www.serviceUrl.com')
   .then(res => res.json())
    .then(value => {
        this.setState({
            value: value.empRecords,  //Here its getting all records from json
            default: false
        });        
    })
```

Let me know guys if any more information is required.

Comment: Cant you just save the rows in an array in state?

Comment: @ChrisRosenlind - I am saving in an array, i have edited the Post including both how i am initializing State and setting State

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get the sum using `reduce`:

```
const SumValue = this.state.value && this.state.value.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0)
```

Comment: After using the above statement i am getting sumValue - undefined! - @Miguel

Comment: What's the `this.state.value` array elements schema? I mean, are they objects or numbers, like: `this.state.value = [1, 2, 3]` or `this.state.value = [{ Col1: 1}, { Col1: 2}, { Col1: 3}]`?

Comment: Json file is like below
'{"empRecords":
[{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}{"value":4}]}' @Miguel

Comment: This should work then: `const SumValue = this.state.value && this.state.value.reduce((a, v) => a + v.value, 0)`

Comment: I am aware of react, need help from you @Miguel on transforming my entire application to redux, for ex- where to place above service call from componentDidMount in redux either in reducers or Actions ??

Comment: I'd place it in actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164605/discussion-between-martin-m-and-miguel).

Answer (score 0):

```
1) initial columnNames and array list

state = {
    callList: [],
    columnModel: [
       { columnName: "date" },
       { columnName: "totalCalls" },
       { columnName: "answeredCalls" },
       { columnName: "abandonedCalls" },
       { columnName: "abandonRate" },
       { columnName: "avgAnswerSpeed" },
    ]

};

2) Get data from api and prepare array data

try {
    const { errors, list, success } = (await apiService.getCalls(request)).data;
    if (success) {

        // first list is normal numbers count only, 
        // if you want count avg sum for some columns send second param array list and include column names
        // now i want count avg for 'abandonRate', 'avgAnswerSpeed' , others just count sum

        this.setState({ 
            callList: list,
            callListSum: this.sumCount(
                list, 
                ['abandonRate', 'avgAnswerSpeed']
            )
        })
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}

sumCount = (list = [], avgColumns = []) => {
    const sum = {};

    // count numbers
    list.map((item) => {
        Object.entries(item).map(([key, val]) => {
            if (typeof (val) === 'number') {
                sum[key] = sum[key] ? (sum[key] + val) : val;
            }
        })
    });
    
    // count avg
    avgColumns.map(key => {
        if (sum[key]) {
            sum[key] = sum[key] / list.length;
        }
    })
    return sum;
}


3) Render data

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F7FA" }}>
            {
                this.state.columnModel.map((item, i) =>
                  <th key={i}> {item.columnName}</th>
                )
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {
            this.state.callList.map(
            (info, index) => (
                <tr
                    key={index}
                >
                    {
                        this.state.columnModel.map((item, i) =>
                           (
                            <td key={i}>
                              {info[item.columnName]}
                            </td>
                           )
                        )
                    }
                </tr>
            )
        )}
        {/* Render sum area */}
        <tr 
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F7FA" }}
        >
            {
                this.state.columnModel.map((item, i) =>
                    (
                        <td style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} >
                         {this.state.callListSum[item.columnName]}
                        </td>
                    )
                )
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```